# How to convert hyphenated date (01-02-2003) to slashed date (01/02/2003) in google sheets (Format not working)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a GoogleSheet that uses the importrange function to import a list of dates from another sheet
I've used the format menu to try and format the date as required, but it reverts back to the hyphenated date again.
How can I either:
a) force it to be a slashed date
b) create another column that converts the date from hyphenated to slashed?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(TO_TEXT(A2:A); "-"; "/"))
```

or if those are true dates:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(A2:A; "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```